# How do I remove the old versions of the linux kernel shown in grub boot loader

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

I am using Ubuntu. I have Linux kernel 3.8.0-35-generic, 2.6.34.14 and 2.6.34.14. I want to delete the 2.6 versions from my system, because 2.6 won't even load when i select them in grub boot loader. How do I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to uninstall them. Read [this](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/).

[SuperUser answers.](https://superuser.com/questions/316990/ubuntu-removing-unused-kernels/316991#316991)

tl;dr.

```
dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | grep -E "(image|headers)" | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Comment: I tried this sir it didnt work i still see my previous versions in grub boot loader